# Algebraically closed field and it's characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra

Ok so my question is motivated by the theory of Lie algebras, and seeing as I'm not that familiar with a lot of group theoretic notions, just the basics really, my question is as follows.
What can be said about a fields characteristic if we know that it is algebraically closed? 
Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Nothing because any field has got an algebraic closure i.e., an extension $\mathbb{K}\subset\mathbb{L}$ such that $\mathbb{L}$ is algebraically closed and obviously the two fields have the same characteristic.